# VM runs very slow using QEMU

Tags: virtualization, performance, qemu

When I create a virtual machine using `qemu-system-x86_64`, it doesn't even boot up. This is how I boot the VM:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -name mac -hda ~/Documents/ubuntu1
```

But when I create the same VM with Oracle [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) or [VMware Player](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Workstation_Player), it runs fine.

What is the issue with QEMU, and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 8):

Be sure to add the `-enable-kvm` option to allow QEMU to use hardware virtualization capabilities (requires Intel VT-x or AMD AMD-V CPU extensions). Without those options, everything will be emulated in software (which is much slower). Example:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 1024 -name mac -hda ~/Documents/ubuntu1
```